# Get index from tuples in list of lists

Tags: python, psychopy

I get keypress and timing output as tuples in a list of lists.

```
output = [[], [], [('m', 2.8167322647641413)], [], [('m', 2.8179350001591956)], [], [], [], [], [], [], [('m', 0.3381059524253942)], []]
```

I manage to select all the non-empty lists using:

```
for i in x:
    if i != []:
        print i
```

How do I also get the corresponding position in the output list?
I tried:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(x):
    print(idx, val)
```

but that gives me all the indices and all lists.

Comment: Think to learn me that psychology software exist in python.

Answer (score 1):

Test `val` if it is non-empty before printing:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(x):
    if val:
       print(idx, val)
```

Comment: When checking for non-emptiness for python list (or other containers), please use the expression `len(thing) == 0`, which is way more clear.